# Mozilla Firefox CSS Box Model Weird Issue

Tags: firefox, css

Try the following sample code:

```
<div style="background-color:#ddd">
<div style="width:900px; margin:0px auto">

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col" style="float:left; width:900px">
            <h1>Title</h1>
        </div>

        <div style="clear:both"></div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>


<div style="background-color:#cfc">
<div style="width:900px; margin:0px auto">

    <div class="row" style="margin-top:10px; border:1px solid #f00">
        <div class="col" style="float:left; width:900px">
            <h2>Content</h2>
        </div>

        <div style="clear:both"></div>
    </div>

</div>
</div>

<div style="background-color:#cfc;">
<div style="width:900px; margin:0px auto">

    <div class="row" style="margin-top:50px; border:1px solid #f00">
        <div class="col" style="float:left; width:900px">
            <h2>Content 2</h2>
        </div>

        <div style="clear:both"></div>
    </div>

</div>
</div>
```

The weird issue is after i set div.row of the Content block to have margin-top:10px, the Title block would move down 10px from top of the browser as well. Any workaround to solve this issue?

Note: No external style sheet is loaded.

Comment: Are you sure only Firefox exhibits this issue?

Comment: I tried on Google Chrome, it works fine. The Title block just sticks to the top of the web browser. The Content block has 10px margin distance from the bottom of the Title block.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for parent `div` of title add the following css `display: inline-block;`

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/HvStn/

Comment: Hello, appreciate your suggestion. Somehow i need the overflow properties of the div blocks, especially the Title block to be visible. It is used as the header section of a web page, which includes a drop down menu.

Comment: @poh another solution could be to add in the first `div` that contains title `display: inline-block;` http://jsfiddle.net/HvStn/

Comment: THANK YOU VERY MUCH! display:inline-block; width:100% seems overcome the issue in Firefox :)